# Cannot install software because of mkdir denial

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, installation-package

So, I have this problem with installing a set of software and at some point the error is:

```
 make[7]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/home/repositories/lalsuite/include/lal'
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/repositories’: Permission denied
Makefile:592: recipe for target 'install-pkgincludeHEADERS' failed
make[7]: *** [install-pkgincludeHEADERS] Error 1
make[7]: Leaving directory '/home/utina/repositories/lalsuite/lal/src/std'
Makefile:708: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[6]: *** [install-am] Error 2
```

I am mentioning that the output of ls -l from the specific folders are:

```
    /repositories/lalsuite$ ls -l
total 368
-rwxrwxr-x  1 utina utina   1223 Jun 24 15:02 00boot
-rw-rw-r--  1 utina utina  29029 Jun 24 15:14 aclocal.m4
drwxr-xr-x  2 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 15:14 autom4te.cache
-rw-rw-r--  1 utina utina  10598 Jun 24 16:48 config.log
-rwxrwxr-x  1 utina utina  26176 Jun 24 16:47 config.status
-rwxrwxr-x  1 utina utina 143165 Jun 24 15:14 configure
-rw-rw-r--  1 utina utina   5439 Jun 24 15:02 configure.ac
drwxrwxr-x 12 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 15:16 glue
drwxrwxr-x  2 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 15:02 gnuscripts
drwxrwxr-x 12 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 16:47 lal
drwxrwxr-x  9 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 16:57 lalapps
drwxrwxr-x 12 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 16:51 lalburst
drwxrwxr-x 12 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 16:51 laldetchar
drwxrwxr-x 12 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 16:47 lalframe
drwxrwxr-x 12 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 16:56 lalinference
drwxrwxr-x 12 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 16:51 lalinspiral
drwxrwxr-x 12 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 16:47 lalmetaio
drwxrwxr-x 12 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 16:54 lalpulsar
drwxrwxr-x 12 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 16:50 lalsimulation
drwxrwxr-x 12 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 16:54 lalstochastic
-rw-rw-r--  1 utina utina   2104 Jun 24 16:48 lalsuiterc
drwxrwxr-x 12 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 16:49 lalxml
drwxrwxr-x  5 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 15:03 lars
drwxrwxr-x  4 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 15:03 ligo
-rw-rw-r--  1 utina utina  30014 Jun 24 16:47 Makefile
-rw-rw-r--  1 utina utina   3099 Jun 24 15:02 Makefile.am
-rw-rw-r--  1 utina utina  29510 Jun 24 15:14 Makefile.in
drwxrwxr-x 13 utina utina   4096 Jun 24 15:16 pylal
```

Also:

```
utina@utinax55:~/repositories$ ls -l
total 2576
drwxrwxr-x 21 utina utina    4096 Jun 24 16:48 lalsuite
drwxrwxr-x  9 utina utina    4096 Jun 24 15:14 metaio
drwxrwxr-x 15 utina utina    4096 Jun 24 15:13 v8r26
-rw-rw-r--  1 utina utina 2624760 May 17  2015 v8r26.tar.gz
```

So, the execute permissions for the specific folders seem to be applied; any ideas?

Comment: What commands did you type to attempt to install `lalsuite`?

Comment: I tried to install it from the source; (./configure, make and make install)

Comment: At which of the 3 steps did you see the error?

Comment: at the installation procedure (make install)

Comment: Ubuntu : The install command is `sudo make install` ... for installing files to a location outside your /home/[name]/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't explained why it's trying to write to `/home/repositories` and not `/home/utina/repositories`.  I'm guessing that you have put `~repositories` somewhere, when you meant `~/repositories`.

Comment: So, /home/repositories/lalsuite is the package were I am running the source code from; i don't see were /home/utina/ is.

Comment: The error message indicates that there is no `/home/repositories` directory. (Normally that directory would exist only if you have an account with the user name `repositories`.)  Note that `~repositories` would expand to `/home/repositories` only if that account exists, and only if that's its home directory.

Comment: So, the script is trying to create a folder in the home directory. Is there any solution to change this?

Comment: So it seemed that 'sudo make install' forced the installation procedure but the software was still inaccessible. For people having the same issue I recommend solving all the dependencies using a package manager and then install it from the source code or else.